# roslibjs audio_common_msgs wrong array length

Tags: ros, roslibjs

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I publish audio_common_msgs Audiodata from my ros module and subscribe to it via roslibjs

```
    var audio_topic = new ROSLIB.Topic({
    ros : ros,
    name : '/camera/audio',
    messageType : 'audio_common_msgs/AudioData'
});
```

It works but the length of the data is incorrect. I send predefined array sizes of 512 and check in my ros module if the length is really 512. However in my roslibjs webpage the data is of length 684. I dont know where the other array values come from. Can someone help me out?

thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/253258/roslibjs-audio_common_msgs-wrong-array-length/) by [Swoncen](https://answers.ros.org/users/26982/swoncen/) on ROS Answers with karma: 23 on 2017-01-29

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [dinesh](https://answers.ros.org/users/26847/dinesh/) on 2020-04-17**:
Can u share u'r code how u played the audio using roslibjs? i'm really stuck in it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Could it be that the binary data is encoded as `base64`? Similar to how images are encoded in roslibjs?

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2017-01-30

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Swoncen](https://answers.ros.org/users/26982/swoncen/) on 2017-01-30**:
Excellent comment. This was so obvious but I didn't think of it. I try to enocde it in the evening and see if it's true. base64: 64 = 2^6, so 6 bits instead of 8: (512/6) *8 = 682,6. So it is not exactly 684, but very close and it could be filled up to 684 (next even number) or something like that.

**Comment by [Swoncen](https://answers.ros.org/users/26982/swoncen/) on 2017-01-30**:
It's correct with "atob()". Thanks!